# Bootstrap: Expanded navbar switch to menu icon that makes overlay navbar on click

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to understand how to get this work. I have a navbar with logo on left and menu links on the right. When the screen reaches 768px, menu links should disappear and menu icon should show up instead. And when menu icon is pressed, menu overlay should appear with those links and some button and links.

My example below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark" id="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="company-logo" src="img/company-logo.svg"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target="#collapsingNavbarMd">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbarMd">
        <ul class="nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#works">Works</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#contact-us">Contact Us</a>
          </li>
          <section class="contact-buttons">
            <div class="ask-button">
              <button class="btn-outlined">Ask me</button>
            </div>
            <div class="social-icons">
              <div class="whatsapp-icon social-icon">
                <img src="img/whatsapp-icon.svg" alt="WhatsApp">
              </div>
              <div class="linkedin-icon social-icon">
                <img src="img/linkedin-icon.svg" alt="LinkedIn">
              </div>
              <div class="facebook-icon social-icon">
                <img src="img/facebook-icon.svg" alt="Facebook">
              </div>
              <div class="twitter-icon social-icon">
                <img src="img/twitter-icon.svg" alt="Twitter">
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar {
  padding: 0;
  .company-logo {
    width: 140px;
    height: auto;
  }
  .company-logo:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
  }
}

.navbar .container {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar .contact-buttons {
  display: none;
}

.navbar button {
  display: block;
}

.navbar-right .nav-item .nav-link {
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 2.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.navbar-dark .navbar-toggler {
  border-color: transparent;
  z-index: 2;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  button:focus {
    outline: none;
  }
}

.navbar-expand-md .container {
  padding-right: 30px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.navbar-expand-md .navbar-collapse {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

Overlay style should be like this:

```
.navbar-overlay {
  display: block;
  background-color: #585858;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  .container {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 12vh;
    ul {
      flex-direction: column;
    }
  }
  .navbar-right .nav-item .nav-link {
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-weight: 500;
  }
  .company-logo {
    display: none;
  }
  .contact-buttons {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS code?

Comment: @Chillie Just added.